# Determine Central SharePoint Administration for SP site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I have access to one Central SharePoint Administration application which does not seem to list the web application for which I need Central SharePoint Administration access.  What is the fastest way to determine the server for which Central SharePoint Administration for a particular sharepoint site is on?

Comment: Just to be sure - can you define "CSA"

Comment: I'm assuming he may mean Central SharePoint Administration? Taking a guess from his tags.

Comment: Central SharePoint Administration

Comment: You mean, you are on Central Admin site of your farm and you cannot see the web application / site collection which you looking far, correct? how many farm you have? do you know the URL of the site /webapplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Central Administration does not have the site you are looking for there are a couple reasons why:

- The site you are looking for is in another farm (which will be a separate Central Administration site). Most clients/companies do not have more than one production farm.
- The site you are looking for is on a separate content database that is offline or is not mounted.
- The farm you are looking at is not the right farm for the site.

Do you have farm administration access?

Comment: My manager has Farm Administrator access.

Comment: If he can't see the site in Central Administration, then it's on another farm. Have you tried looking at the site collections for each web application?

Comment: I think most likely it was dismounted. Most clients these days only have one farm.